# Java - compare date submitted through form to date stored in mysql db - How?

Tags: java, mysql, forms, jsp, datetime

I'm creating a custom online user interface. A jsp page has a form where the user can select a date from a calendar (made with JavaScript) and also specify the exact time the event will take place.

My servlet reads in the form data, which will end up looking like this :
The date : 2012-MAR-12 
The time : 7:00 p.m.

The day and time need to be stored in the mysql database table. I set the column to a DATETIME type.

I want to take the date values in that column, compare them to the 'current date + 30 mins', and show only the events that meet that criteria.

1) How do I convert the string values of the date and time, sent in from the form, to a DATETIME value to store in the database?

2) How do I compare those date/time entries in the db to the current date and time?

Answer (score 2):

To convert the String to a date you can use the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class. This has some built in methods to convert Strings to dates in a variety of formats.

For example:

```
    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");
    Date mydate = fmt.parse("2012-Mar-04", 0);
```

Now you can use mydate to compare to the date in MySQL.

For your second question, you can get teh current system time by instantiating a new Date.

```
    Date now = new Date();
```

Then use that to compare the date in the MySQL table with a simple SQL statement. I assume that you are using a Prepared statement of some sort.

```
   PreparedStatement currentEvents = con.prepareStatement("Select * from mytable where thedate = ?");
   currentEvents.setDate(1, mydate);
   result = currentEvents.executeQuery();
```

where con is your connection and so on...

Comment: The first block of code with the SimpleDateFormat example doesn't work. How can I add 30 mins or so to the current date for comparison then to the database entries? I need to be able to compare the time and not only the date...is that going to be possible?

Comment: Of course. Look at the SimpleDateFormat docs that I linked to to see the patterns that you can create to specify the dates and times in a number of ways. You choose the way that suits you best. If you have to do a lot of date manipulation then either switch to java.util.Calendar or joda time (http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I agree that it is a tiny bit confusing that Java stores both Date and Time in a class called Date. You can get used to it, though.

Comment: Don't use `setDate()` for a `TIMESTAMP`/`DATETIME` field. Use `setTimestamp()` instead. The `java.sql.Date` contains only the date portion, not the time portion.

Answer (score 0):

To parse your input, use this code:

```
String dateInput = "2012-MAR-12";
String timeInput = "7:00 p.m.";

SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-ddh:mm a");
String s = dateInput + timeInput.replace(".", ""); // must remove the dots
Date d = f.parse(s);
```

Once you have your date, you can use it directly via JDBC. I would do all date comparisons in your query. I don't understand what you are trying to do, but try something like this:

```
select * from table where datetime_col between ? and adddate(?, interval 30 minutes)
```

Pass the data object in twice as parameters to your JDBC call.